# Why onItemSelected not working with setOnCheckedChangeListener?

Tags: android, android-studio

that's my first post here:)

I want to create simple activity with two RadioButton and Spinner.
Spinner gets data from DB, display it, and run task after click on selected item. After add two RadioButtons to make something like filter on my data I got annoying error - data is displayed, but onItemSelected doesn't run task(start next activity). So I have no idea, how to resolved this issue.

```
public class TrackSpinner extends Activity{

class MyRadioButton {
    private List<String> routes = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getRoutes() {
        return (routes);
    }

    public List<String> addRoutes(List<String> a) {
        routes.clear();
        routes.addAll(a);
        routes.add(0, getString(R.string.trackSpinner1));
        return routes;
    }

    public List<String> noRoutes() {
        routes.clear();
        routes.add(0, getString(R.string.trackSpinner2));
        return routes;
    }
}

public void trackInfo(String jpg, String describtion) {
    Intent i = new Intent(TrackSpinner.this, ShowTrack.class);
    i.putExtra("obrazek", jpg);
    i.putExtra("opis", describtion);
    startActivity(i);
}

public String[] getDataAboutRoute (String sdisr){
    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    ArrayList<String> route = databaseAccess.getAllDescriptionsFromRouteArray(sdisr);
    databaseAccess.close();
    String desr = route.get(0);
    String img = route.get(1);
    return new String[] {img, desr};
}

private boolean isSpinnerTouched = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.object_list_for_track);
    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    final List<String> routes = databaseAccess.getAvailableRoute();
    databaseAccess.close();
    final RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    final RadioButton r2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup) ;
    final MyRadioButton r = new MyRadioButton();


    Log.e("4---->", String.valueOf(r.getRoutes()));

    final Spinner trackSpinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dynamic_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, r.getRoutes());
    trackSpinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    trackSpinner1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.performClick();
            isSpinnerTouched = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    trackSpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (!isSpinnerTouched) return;
            String short_name = trackSpinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Log.e("5---->", String.valueOf(short_name));
            getDataAboutRoute(short_name);
            String result[] = getDataAboutRoute(short_name);
            trackInfo(result[0], result[1]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if(r1.isChecked())
            {
                r.addRoutes(routes);
                //Log.e("---->", String.valueOf(r.getRoutes()));
            }
            else if (r2.isChecked())
            {
                r.noRoutes();
                //Log.e("---->", String.valueOf(r.getRoutes()));
            }
            else {
                Log.e("---->", "OK, here I'm");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

[And how it's look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5qzn.png)

Comment: why are you adding ontouchlistener on spinner?

Comment: I want to avoid autoselect first entry from my spinner, during start activity.

Comment: so you mean to say that if you dont use onItemTouch then during start activity onItemSelected will get called automatically?

Comment: I should remove it. It's code that remained before being added setOnCheckedChangeListener and RadioButtons. Now onItemSelected generally does't work. After clean up, results it's the same.